# Convert array of key-value pairs into associative array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I currently have an Array:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100011
        [1] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100013
        [1] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100022
        [1] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100025
        [1] => 1
```

I want to take the first child item (meaning [0]) of each array (1,2,3,4,etc) and put it into a new array. I know I need to loop through and assign the value to new array. Just not sure how to do it.

**End result would be:**

$final (name of new array) has values 100013,100022,100025,etc.

**My real end result:**

I need it kept in the same order, because I am then going to use `array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )` to create 100013 as the key and 1 as the value, 100022 as the key, 1 as the value, 100025 as the key, 1 as the value.

If you know a quicker way to accomplish, it is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `array_column($arr, 0)`

Comment: @Ja͢ck genius. that did the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you right, the final result can be obtained by doing:

```
array_combine(array_column($arr, 0), array_column($arr, 1));
```

Or, in a more traditional way:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as list($key, $value)) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: hi @Jack, Did u test speed between two this way with a large array?

Comment: @RyanNghiem no, but i would imagine that the modern way uses more memory for sure!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$results = array();
foreach($array as $item)
{
  $results[] = $item[0];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if  (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)

```
 $first_names = array_column($records, 0);
 print '<pre>';
 print_r($first_names);
```

Another way,

```
function one_dimension($n) 
{
 return $n[0];
}

$result =array_map("one_dimension", $records);
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```