# Convert array of key-value pairs into associative array without using column names

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array from a database query:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [div_id] => 21 [div_name] => "Alphabet" )
  [1] => Array ( [div_id] => 16 [div_name] => "Elementary" )
  [2] => Array ( [div_id] => 19 [div_name] => "Preschool" )
  [3] => Array ( [div_id] => 20 [div_name] => "Secondary" )
)
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
Array ( 
  [21] => "Alphabet"
  [16] => "Elementary"
  [19] => "Preschool"
  [20] => "Secondary"
)
```

However, **I can't use the key names**.  I need to reference them as the first and second columns, since in my context I can't control the keys of the source data.  I need to use the same algorithm on data with different key names, for example:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [unknown_id] => 21 [random] => "Alphabet" )
  [1] => Array ( [unknown_id] => 16 [random] => "Elementary" )
  [2] => Array ( [unknown_id] => 19 [random] => "Preschool" )
  [3] => Array ( [unknown_id] => 20 [random] => "Secondary" )
)
```

The question is very similar to [Convert array of key-value pairs into associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550173/convert-array-of-key-value-pairs-into-associative-array) but that had [0] and [1] for the keys, and I have text keys but still need to reference the first and second items of the arrays.

Comment: Worst comes to worst, just iterate through the array and do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$indexed = array_map('array_values', $data);
$res = array_combine(array_column($indexed, 0), array_column($indexed, 1));
```

Or with the 3rd argument of `array_column`:

```
$res = array_column(array_map('array_values', $data), 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a built-in function to do exactly this.  Use the third parameter to index the array by a specific column:

```
$result = array_column($array, 'div_name', 'div_id');
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Comment: Please remember that I can't use the key names.  This solution does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Because using functional programming on your unpredictable keys leads to unnecessary convolution and excess iterating. You should use a classic `foreach()` loops to set up your new data structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XvOkZ))

```
$array = [
  ["unknown_id1" => 21, "randomA" => "Alphabet"],
  ["unknown_id2" => 16, "randBom" => "Elementary"],
  ["unknown_id3" => 19, "raCndom" => "Preschool"],
  ["unknown_id4" => 20, "Drandom" => "Secondary"]
];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[current($row)] = end($row);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  21 => 'Alphabet',
  16 => 'Elementary',
  19 => 'Preschool',
  20 => 'Secondary',
)
```